# Lock the formula of a cell, even if the cells it references change

Tags: google-sheets

I have this, in D1:

```
=sum(D3:D)
```

I want D1 to always be the sum of the rest of column D (D2 is a header)

I sometimes move a row, from eg 8 to 3, and that causes D1 to change to sum(d4:d).

I want D1 to stay as my sum of the column.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Short answer

Use `=SUM(INDIRECT("D2:D"))`

## Explanation

Google Sheets will update A1 notation references when rows or columns are inserted, so if you need that a reference never changes, instead you have to use a string and the INDIRECT() function to convert it to a reference.

## References

- [INDIRECT - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Comment: so, it's kinda like eval() ?  (php)

Comment: @DougCassidy: I don't think so. INDIRECT only returns a cell/range reference, it don't execute code.

Answer (score 3):

With INDIRECT, I had trouble when I inserted a new row or column and everything shifted and that's where [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472) comes in.

Use `=sum(OFFSET(D2:D,1,0))`

This will make sure your formula is correctly updated when you insert cells and when you copy paste them.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way: `=sum(D$3:D)`. the $ locks the starting row.

Comment: No, this does not do what the OP wants. If you insert a row on top, the formula will be changed to `=sum(D$4:D)`.  He wants it to start from the 3rd row, even if new rows are added/deleted/moved.

Comment: You are right. It looks $ only locks the value when copying formulas

Comment: @user79865 is there a way to apply the formula for the inserted above row?

Answer (score 0):

I'm becoming acutely aware that certain functions that interpret contents are very time consuming.  Indirect is one of the ones I avoid.

Another approach is to put a buffer row at the start and end of the row range.  You can make the height small, and fill with a colour or hide the row.

So Row 1 is headers
Row 2 is whatever you currently have as row 2.
Row 3 is your buffer row. 
D1 = sum(D$3:D)

Now you can rearrange as you want.

If you include Row 3 in your frozen header section, you can even sort your spreadsheet.  It won't affect the frozen rows.