# How to prevent row/column insertion/deletion from breaking links to other sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Earlier I asked this question: [How to create a link with content bound to other cell's content in Google sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/146402/255143)

And until now the provided solution was working perfectly for me but now, the problem is: I just realized that whenever I insert/delete a row/column from my referenced sheet the links generated using the aforementioned question's answer will become broken and will link to an other cell/range.

**Here's an example to reproduce:**

- On a first sheet, fill A1 with some text
- On a second sheet, create a link to A1 (using the aforementioned question's answer)
- Use the link to come back to the first sheet, you should have your cell with text selected
- Insert a row above row 1
- Come back to second sheet and try to use the link again : it now selected an empty cell on row one instead of selecting the cell with your text

How can I overcome this problem and have "stable" links that always send me to the same cell using its "reference" and not its location?

Comment: As questions should be self-contained, show in this question what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

I found the trick to fix this issue : using the link as explained in [the answer to the question mentionned in this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146403/255143),  in the `gid=someId&range=SomeLocation` part, remove the right part of the `=` (to end up with something like `gid=someId&range=`).
Use the [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) function to build the [`HYPERLINK`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en)'s first parameter and build the right part of the `=` using [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en) and/or [`COLUMN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en) functions.

For example, using the question's example, the cell containing the hyperlink's formula will look like this : `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("gid=someId&range=";COLUMN(FirstSheet!A1);ROW(FirstSheet!A1));"This is a stable link")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using actual references, i.e. `A1`, use `INDIRECT`, i.e. `INDIRECT("A1")`

Related

- [Lock the formula of a cell, even if the cells it references change](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88994/88163)
- [Prevent dragging and dropping from changing cells referencing moved cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102214/88163)
- [Google Sheets Cell Reference](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114136/88163)
- [Locking a formula when adding rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/148763/88163)

Comment: using INDIRECT doesn't give me a link like HYPERLINK does and moreover it is still affected by row/column deletion/inserstion the same way it is with my actual linking method

Comment: I didn't suggested to use INDIRECT instead of HYPERLINK

Comment: Then how am I meant to use INDIRECT to have a link like HYPERLINK?

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me. This is how it did it:

`=LET(myCell,'SomeSheet'!A1,HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#gid=0&range=",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address", myCell),"'SomeSheet'!",""),"$","")),myCell))`

The `LET(myCell, 'SomeSheet'!A1, ...)` is just for setting a variable (`myCell`, which is a reference to the cell we need to "fixate" to), and then be able to reuse it across the formula.

`CELL("address", myCell)` will return `SomeSheet'!$A$1`.

From there, it's just a matter of doing some substitutions (we remove the sheet's name, and then the "$" symbol) until we get something like `#gid=0&range=A1`, which is the URL for the sheet & cell we want to link to.